# spring restful web service logging

Tags: spring, rest, logging

I implemented Spring RESTful Web Service using this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/. I added dependencies for log4j in pom.xml and log4j.properties file in src/main/resources folder. Now I expect logging to be done into log file as stated inthe log4j.properties file instead of to STDOUT. However, logging goes only to STDOUT. How can I fix tis to print log messages to log file?

Comment: Did you read this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Spring Boot uses LogBack as logging framework.
If you want to configure Log4J, [follow this configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging). 
You need to exclude Spring Boot's logging module (containing LogBack dependency) and include Spring boot started for log4j.

BTW, log4j is ancient technology, consider moving to logback or log4j2

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I followed the configuration instructions and decided to switched to log4j2 because log4j did not write to log file no matter what I tried.